# Animation between changes of on/off state of UISwitch broken due to change of thumbTintColor

Tags: ios, swift, uiswitch

I've been given a design where each and every `UISwitch` has one `thumbTintColor` for it's on state and a different one for the off state. What I'm trying to accomplish is implementing this design but so far I'm at a loss as to why the animation which is supposed to transition the thumbs origin from right to left, or vise versa, for lack of more appropriate words gets totally messed up.

Basically when a switch gets tapped its thumb, instead of sliding from one end to the other, gets distorted and appears instantly on the other end of the switch. This is as close as I can describe the distortion without providing a video of the actual anomaly.

My, albeit wild, guess is that this has something to do with the inner workings of `UIKit` and `animatable`, or lack of, properties of certain `UIControls`. So far the only conclusion that I've come to is to ditch the standard `UISwitch` and make a custom `UIControl` which seems overkill for something this trivial.

The code to reproduce this behavior is in the following method connected to a `UISwitch` in a tableView cell:

```
    @IBAction func allWheelDriveSwitchValueChanged(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    if sender.isOn {
        sender.thumbTintColor = AppColor.myYellow
    } else {
        sender.thumbTintColor = AppColor.darkGray
    }
}
```

Where `AppColor` is an enum with preset `UIColor` objects. I've tried putting this in animation blocks with calling `layoutIfNeeded` from the cell's contentView but to no avail.

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried doing this

```
@IBAction func allWheelDriveSwitchValueChanged(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    if sender.isOn {
        sender.thumbTintColor = UIColor.yellow
    } else {
        sender.thumbTintColor = UIColor.darkGray
    }
}
```

instead of

```
@IBAction func allWheelDriveSwitchValueChanged(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    if sender.isOn {
        sender.thumbTintColor = AppColor.myYellow
    } else {
        sender.thumbTintColor = AppColor.darkGray
    }
}
```

This is the thing with enums :

> The downside to dropping the raw type is that you must provide some
>   logic for parsing the known enum values. The upside, however, is that
>   you can fit anything else into a single Unknown case, while keeping
>   the actual "unknown" value available for later use

Comment: Hi, I've tried that and the problem still persists. This enum is only a wrapper for a static method that maps hex values to UIColors, and stores those colors as static props. It actually has no cases, just a one single method and for all intents and purposes it might as well have been a struct so it's completely unrelated to my issue. Thanks though.